QGIS point sampling misses data on edge of raster (possible bug?)
It seems I may have discovered a shortcoming in the way QGIS handles raster sampling in points. Since yesterday evening (18/7), one small issue has begun to elude me (during my comeback geofictional assignment): Through SAGA or GRASS, at least, the software misses the bottom-most points of a vector whose dimensions are exactly the same as a DEM raster I'm trying them on. Everything else gets filled in neatly; the bottom nodes only receive a NULL token each. (In the scenario now up for grabs, both layers measure 0.75° by 0.75° and originated in WGS84; raster dimensions are 5400 x 5400, 1/7200 resolution.)
This might be a bug on QGIS' own end, but I can't be quite so sure yet. (Not to mention this is my first GIS.SE filing in more than half a decade.)

with out seeing the data it's impossible for us to tell what's going on, but the most likely issue is a difference between greater than and greater than or equal being used to detect intersections

At your request, Mr. @Ian_Turton, here's a GDrive folder with the files in question. (Released, as with the rest of its parent project, under CC0/Kopimi.)

It's not just the bottom row, it's the right side points as well.

And this is not really a bug, it's just the way raster indexing works.  It affects other software as well.
Rasters are indexed top down and left to right. So when the software calculates the raster row and col index from your point coordinates using an affine transform (aka geotransform) for that last row or column of points, it will get the next row down or column across and since there isn't a next row or column, you get null for all those points.
